# UIScrollView problems

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiscrollview

I've implemented a scrollview that loads 8 images, I also have 8 images with interaction enabled and touch events so when a user touches one of the 8 images the scrollview scrolls to that position, the user can also scroll manually. All works great apart from one thing.

If you scroll to say page 4 in the scrollview, then decide you want to view image 8 and touch the 8th image, the scrollview will scroll to that image correctly, the problem is that if you now touch the scrollview it automatically scrolls back to page 4, which I don't want to do.

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want help on this one it would be better to provide some code example. Right now it's quite hard to say anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, it was to do with **paging mode**, so I only enable paging when **tracking** and **dragging** and disable it at all other times, this works great now.